# Highstock performance issue

Tags: highcharts

When use Highstock we meet a performance issue when we use the line with compare.
We need to add 15 line series and each series have 800 points. And it will cause the "Stop running this scripts" issue in IE 8 or lower.

And this happens not only when we add data to the chart, when we change the size of the chart this also happened.

Does anyone have experience on this issue ?

In IE 9 or other browser it works well but the performance is a bad.

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768021/highcharts-performance-enhancement-method

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried modify turbothreshold parameter? 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Take look at http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts

Morever you can try to disable animations / markers / shadows to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The performance improved, but in IE8 and lower for 15 series and each series with 800 points still get the "Stop running this scripts" issue. Because in our requirements we need to show all the data at the same time, so we can not use lazy loading. Is there other way to improve the performance in IE8 or lower?

Comment: Is is possible to reproduce your issue in the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It is hard to create so many data on the jsfiddle. If I can get so many data i think i can reproduce it.