# Unable to set the Selected state in Highcharts, when point marker is disabled

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to show the points in a line chart as selected even though the point-marker is disabled. But, it's not working. Could anyone help me with this?

This is an example from Highcharts API doc, my requirement is similar

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                marker: {
                    enabled : false,
                    states: {
                        select: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Any console (F12) error? If you use exactly that code, you do not reproduce the output?

Comment: @nicolallias... no console error...Although , i din get the second part of ur question "If you use exactly that code, you do not reproduce the output?"

Comment: "I am trying [...] But, its not working.": what code does not work? Yours or that from Highcharts?

Comment: my code is not working...my intention is to show a line chart without the point-markers in normal state...and when I select a point ...that particular point should be shown as "selected"... but, it's not happening.. with above mentioned approach... 
Please note that on hover the points are shown.

Comment: Can you show us your malfunctioning code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roytirthadeep/68ukq1hs/

this is the fiddle link... my requirement is this....

Comment: I do not get it: that fiddle is the same as your code ; you tell us that your code does not work as you want but only show us the documentation code (which works). Where is yours? We cannot debug a functioning code, we may debug a malfunctioning one if we can read it.

Comment: the documentation code is working for you ?... i mean if u select a point ...whether the point is shown as selected (i.e. as a circle with black border and white fillcolor) ?...if that is the case ...then something is wrong with my browser

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you want. Have a look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.select and http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.unselect to try to tweak the behaviour of selection.

Comment: You can set radius marker as 1 and then select state works. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/68ukq1hs/1/

Comment: ya I have already gone through the API documentation... but could not find any such help... thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1

You can set `radius marker as 1` and then select state works. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/68ukq1hs/1

## Solution 2

Disable marker and then catch click event on particular point. Next step is call point.update() on point to show marker.

```
point:{
                events:{
                    click:function(){
                        var serie = this.series,
                            flag = this.marker && this.marker.enabled ? false : true;
                        
                        //remove old point
                        if(serie.prevPoint) {
                            serie.prevPoint.update({
                                marker:{
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            },false);
                        }
                        
                        serie.prevPoint = this;
                        
                        this.update({
                            marker:{
                                enabled: flag
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/11pLzk9m/2/

Comment: Actually, I am trying improve the performance of highcharts rendering  by disabling the point-markers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768021/highcharts-performance-enhancement-method
But, I need to show them as selected when I click on them(point)... could u please help me in this... ur solution is awesome... but here we are keeping point-marker enabled....

Also, if u cud suggest some work around...